# Presentmodalviewcontroller causes mkmapview to disappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hitting my head against a wall here. Feel like this should be simple, but just can't figure it out.

I have a Window with a UIViewController set as its rootviewcontroller.  In the rootviewcontroller, I have a full screen mkmapview. Catch is, when presentmodalviewcontroller gets called, I see my mkmapview completely disappear (the color of my viewcontroller's view underneath instantly comes up) just as the new screen comes flying in.  Once I dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, it goes back to a (black) screen.

I've tested this a bit by removing the iboutlet of the mapview in IB - then the transitions work like a charm.

I don't think it's this code as I'm using the template Utility app as a guide - but just to give some substance:

```
-(IBAction)settingsGearPressed:(id)sender
{    
    SettingsViewController *controller = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I was removing the mapview in ViewWillDissapear